# How to have two executeNonQuery inside a ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have this query, `ExecuteReader`, and inside of it, two `ExecuteNonQuery`. It doesn't do anything. I've tried to put the two `executeNonQuery` under `cmd1` and `cmd2` but it doesn't allow that because the `executeReader` is open. What steps do I need to take to correct this issue?

```
   private void btnSTART_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    string path = null;//estrazione1
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select nomeI  FROM tabL where selection=1", sqliteCon);
    SqlDataReader nomeIRdr = null;//estrazione2
    nomeIRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//estrazione3
    while (nomeIRdr.Read())//estrazione4
    {
      path = nomeIRdr["nomeI"].ToString();//estrazione5

    }
    using (nomeIRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())//cmd.ExecuteReader() gives me the error cmd doesn't exist in the current 
    {
      sqliteCon.Open();
      if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
      {
        Process MyProc = Process.Start(path);//permette la run del path contenuto nel db
        MyProc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = MyProc.ExitCode;

        if (exitCode == 1)
        {
          SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into tabL resI values 'PASS'", sqliteCon);
          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
          SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into tabL resI values 'FAIL'", sqliteCon);
          cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
      sqliteCon.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Items Started"); 
  }
  sqliteCon.Close();

}
```

If the solution is that it doesn't work,same error of the beginning of that question

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can't use the connection while the reader is not disposed, so you must create a new connection for each `cmd1` and `cmd2`

Comment: it's about connection ... either use different(one connection for rader another for inserts) or allow this connection  to have multiple active resultsets(if it's mssql) ... it is easy to find when you would google for your excpetion ...

Comment: when o run the code simply cmd and cmd1 don't do anything

Comment: You could check these links: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/database/article.php/c8715/Want-to-Execute-Multiple-Queries-on-a-Single-Connection-Go-to-MARS.htm & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Magnetron i've tryied that too but doing so i'll have two connections inside another one

Comment: ... anyway ... I would not recomend do this at all ... instead  use reader to fill some list ... close reader ... then iterate list and do the stuff

Comment: @madcodroipo what's the problem with that? Anyway, you can follow PaulF link to use the same connection

Comment: yup,maybe.... i don't know if it works written like this because it doesn't tell me anything and it doesn't do anything

Comment: I'm going to go with @Magnetron on this one. I believe you will need to close that reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) that `ExecuteReader` returns is a server cursor, this means that the connection will be used exclusively by the reader until you close it. So you won't be able to run any other command using the same connection.

What I would do keeping in a list what you have to do (those inserts) and after the reader is closed perform all the operations you need to perform.

You can use a `using` block so the reader is closed and disposed. After doing that you can reuse the same connection.

```cs
using (var nomeItemRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
} 
//You can reuse your connection here.
```

Comment: doing execute non query in a new connection after the reader connection is closed?

Comment: @madcodroipo as long as the **reader** is disposed, that's all you need - you don't need a new connection

Comment: i'm not understanding i'm reading the pages linkend but i'm not believing that to do that i've to use MARS or things like that. and i'm not understanding what i've to do have i to close the connection of the reader and then execute the queries that are inside of the if's  that are in another connection?

Comment: @madcodroipo Added `using` example @MarcGravell

Comment: @hardkoded i've updated the code with the interpretation of your suggestion but mybe it isn't right...could you only watch where is the problem with tha implementation?

Comment: You have to figure out how to move cmd1 and cmd2 out of the using.

Comment: the code above is the result of the  attempt to apply your suggestion to my code,but i don't know what could i do after that i'm just a student non an expert, and i'm sailing in unknown waters yet