# ExecuteReader query with inside of it two ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I've got a problem with some queries from c# to SQL. I need to have a query executeReader and inside of it a if else that allow me to choose between two inserts queries. I'm calling a little external program(with the URL collected into the db) which allows me to choose between 1 and 2, if the 1 is chosen(pass) else(fail). I can't do that because the debug is giving me:

> 'A Command is yet associated with a DataReader opened, which needs to be closed.'

I don't know what to try anymore.

```
private void btnSTART_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    string path = null;//estrazione1
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select nomeI  FROM tabL where selection=1", sqliteCon);
    SqlDataReader nomeIRdr = null;//estrazione2
   
                    //qui                  
    var scriptsToRun = new List<string>();

    using (nomeIRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (nomeIRdr.Read())//estrazione4
      {
        path = nomeIRdr["nomeI"].ToString();//estrazione5

        Process MyProc = Process.Start(path);//permette la run del path contenuto nel db
        MyProc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = MyProc.ExitCode;
  
        if (exitCode == 1)
        {
          scriptsToRun.Add("insert into tabL resItem values 'PASS'");
        }
        else
        {
          scriptsToRun.Add("insert into tabL resItem values 'FAIL'");
        }
        sqliteCon.Close();
      }
    
    }
    
    foreach (var script in scriptsToRun)
    {
      SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(script, sqliteCon);
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

  }
  
}
```

Comment: you have two initialization of `nomeItemRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` **first** after the decleration **2nd** in the `using` block.

Comment: oh yeah minor prob i'm going to test it but i don't think is this the problem

Comment: 'Attempt not valid to call Read with reader closed'  still not working:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have two executeNonQuery inside a ExecuteReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399073/how-to-have-two-executenonquery-inside-a-executereader)

Comment: yeah it's mine but noone is going to give me an answer on that question,you know fresh question new possibilities from new answers,could i hide that old question?

Comment: to not duplicate it

Comment: As the error message suggests, you can't *usually* execute two concurrent operations on the same connection (unless you enable "MARS"). So: either you'll need to finish the first operation (i.e. close the reader) before starting the second, or: you'll need two connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not share *single* connection and cram everything into a *single* routine. Please, keep your code *simple*.

1. Create (and Dispose) Connection whenever you query RDBMS
2. Extract methods

**Code:**

Process execution and return execution results collection:

```
// Item1 - path
// Item2 - true in succeed 
private List<Tuple<string, bool>> ExecuteResults() {
  List<Tuple<string, bool>> result = new List<Tuple<string, bool>>();

  using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    con.Open();

    string sql = 
      @"select nomeItem 
          from tabList 
         where selection = 1";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          string path = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);

          using (Process process = Process.Start(path)) {
            process.WaitForExit();

            result.Add(Tuple.Create(path, process.ExitCode == 1)); 
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Saving `results` in RDBMS

```
private void ApplyExecuteResults(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>> results) {
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    con.Open();

    string sql = 
      @"update tabList 
           set resItem = @prm_resItem
         where nomeItem = @prm_nomeItem";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_nomeItem", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_resItem", SqlDbType.VarChar);

      foreach (var item in results) {
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = item.Item1; 
        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = item.Item2 ? "PASS" : "FAIL"; 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Finally, combine both routines:

```
private void btnSTART_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  ApplyExecuteResults(ExecuteResults());
}
```

Comment: While at it, don’t use `AddWithValue` with a magic string but rather add a parameter by specifying its type.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen: Yes, the best option is something `.Add("@prm_resItem", DbType.VarChar);` but I have no idea what is the underlying RDBMS Data type is (is it `VarChar`?). That's why I've added `ToDo`

Comment: @mad codroipo: connections are usually *pooled* (and that's why opening and diposing them are cheap). However, do not *hardcode* the connection string but read it (say, from settings)

Comment: i've screenshotted the code to ask you if it is the right implementation

Comment: @mad codroipo: let's get rid of *ugly* `AddWithValue` then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190894/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-mad-codroipo).

Comment: @mad codroipo: several typos (I'm sorry for them): 
`return result;`
`result.Add(process.ExitCode == 1);`
`foreach (var item in results)`

Comment: where have i to put them? OoO